# Running a Macro on a multiple ppt files within a folder

Tags: vba, file, powerpoint

I found a piece of code that allows me to pull all of the headings from a powerpoint file and type them out in a document. What I would like to be able to do is apply that code to a file of lets say 20 ppt files and pull the titles from each one of those files all at once. Below is the code i used to pull headings from a single file. I was wondering if anyone could help me apply this to a folder full of powerpoints.

```
Sub getTitles()
Dim osld As Slide
Dim sReport As String
Dim iFilenum As Integer
Dim sFilePath As String
For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    If osld.Shapes.HasTitle Then
        If osld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.HasText Then
            sReport = sReport & "Slide  " & osld.SlideIndex & ": " _
                      & osld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange & vbCrLf
        Else:
            sReport = sReport & "Slide  " & osld. _
                      SlideIndex & ": No title text" & vbCrLf
        End If
    Else
        sReport = sReport & "Slide  " & osld. _
                  SlideIndex & ": No title" & vbCrLf
    End If
Next osld
iFilenum = FreeFile
sFilePath = Environ("TEMP") & "\data.txt"
Open sFilePath For Output As iFilenum
Print #iFilenum, sReport
Close iFilenum
Call Shell("Notepad.exe " & sFilePath, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this entry on the PPTFAQ page that I maintain:
https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00536_Batch-_Do_something_to_every_file_in_a_folder.htm

Toward the end of the example, you'll see this:

With oPresentation
' do something
End With

That's the known-working part. The rest needs a few mods to your original subroutine; here's an aircode shot at it:

Change 'do something to Call GetTitles(oPresentation)

```
Sub getTitles(oPresentation as Presentation, sTemp as String)
Dim osld As Slide
Dim sReport As String
Dim iFilenum As Integer
Dim sFilePath As String
For Each osld In oPresentation.Slides
    If osld.Shapes.HasTitle Then
        If osld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.HasText Then
            sReport = sReport & "Slide  " & osld.SlideIndex & ": " _
                      & osld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange & vbCrLf
        Else:
            sReport = sReport & "Slide  " & osld. _
                      SlideIndex & ": No title text" & vbCrLf
        End If
    Else
        sReport = sReport & "Slide  " & osld. _
                  SlideIndex & ": No title" & vbCrLf
    End If
Next osld

sTemp = sTemp & vbcrlf & sReport
' Move the file save and open stuff to the main routine
'iFilenum = FreeFile
'sFilePath = Environ("TEMP") & "\data.txt"
'Open sFilePath For Output As iFilenum
'Print #iFilenum, sReport
'Close iFilenum
'Call Shell("Notepad.exe " & sFilePath, vbNormalFocus)


End Sub
```